# Javascript eval in SAAS apps

Tags: javascript, eval

we are thinking to develop a platform on which: user can create apps for their own users. The platform supports UI editing by drag and drop widgets, and writing code using editor. The wrapper will evaluate the code using `eval` or `new Function` to manipulate logic and UI widgets.

It works, the question is why there are no such kind of platforms that allow user to write code and evaluate code directly out there? The code is written by app owners, which basically is not insecure, so what's the concerns?

Comment: I’m pretty sure there are such tools. `The code is written by app owners, which basically is not insecure, so what's the concerns?` that does not mean it is secure. It always depends one the use case, if multiple users can work on the same project with different access rights, then such scripts could be a potential attack vector to gain more rights within the project.

Comment: "*why there are no such kind of platforms*" - because most "app owners" are not developers that can write code. And those that are write their own software instead of using a SAAS.

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with `eval`, or why `eval` would be necessary here. It sounds like the app owners could just put their own `<script>`s in the code for their own app, couldn't they?

Comment: because it requires context of the wrapper @ber

Comment: So put their custom code in functions that the wrapper calls with the arguments.

Comment: yes that's the plan. I'm just not sure if there are critical weakness with the workflow or pattern. @Bergi

Comment: Ensure that the users trust the owner of the app with their info, not (just) the platform; and make sure to properly separate the apps from each other (i.e. putting them on separate domains)